# shared_ptr - access violation in operator delete

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, shared-ptr

I have an application written in Visual C++ and I struggle with access violation error in this code snippet:

```
game_object_ptr GameObjectFactory::createGameObject(const int& id) {

    game_object_ptr fullObj;
    if(RANGE_PLAYERS_MIN <= id && RANGE_PLAYERS_MAX >= id) {
        fullObj = game_object_ptr(new PlayerCharacter());
    }

    if(fullObj) {
        return fullObj; // Crashes here...
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

`game_object_ptr` is defined like this: `typedef std::shared_ptr<GameObject> game_object_ptr;`

And `PlayerCharacter` class derives from `GameObject`.

Call stack is as follows:

```
msvcr110d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData) Line 52 C++
MyApp.exe!GameObject::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)    C++
MyApp.exe!std::_Ref_count<GameObject>::_Destroy() Line 161  C++
MyApp.exe!std::_Ref_count_base::_Decref() Line 120  C++
MyApp.exe!std::_Ptr_base<GameObject>::_Decref() Line 347    C++
MyApp.exe!std::shared_ptr<GameObject>::~shared_ptr<GameObject>() Line 624   C++
MyApp.exe!GameObjectFactory::createGameObject(const int & id) Line 44   C++ 
(...)
```

So it looks like crash happens while deleting `GameObject` object, suggesting that it is being deleted twice, but I don't have any idea why it is deleted at all, if - as I understand it - the reference count for the shared resource should not go down to 0, as I am passing the ownership further on when calling `createGameObject()` function:

`account->m_characterInGame = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<PlayerCharacter>(GameObjectFactory::createGameObject(characterInfo->m_typeId));`

Does anyone have any clue what's going on here? Maybe I missed something obvious.

EDIT:

`m_characterInGame` is defined like this:
`character_ptr m_characterInGame;`

And `character_ptr`:
`typedef std::shared_ptr<PlayerCharacter> character_ptr;`

Comment: what does `GameObjectManager::addObject()` look like?

Comment: @TheBadger It is not relevant. I just checked without calling it and the problem remains. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Please, see my edited question. I've added definition of `m_characterInGame`.

Comment: Is `account->m_characterInGame` empty when you call this? Perhaps the destructor of the previous instance crashes? You can test by putting `account->m_characterInGame.reset();` before the call to `createGameObject` and see if it crashes there.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Unfortunately not. It still crashes in the same place.

Comment: Then most likely you either have a bug in code not shown or some odd platform/compiler/library problem. See if you can make a self-contained example that replicates the problem. Or try with a different compiler.

Comment: Everything looks OK, perhaps start of with a clean (delete all object and temp files) and rebuild, and if that does not work do what @DavidSchwartz suggested.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but why do you check for a valid pointer at all if you are returning a nullptr in the error case anyway? Aside from this, a self contained example would really help

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Rebuilding did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @MikeMB This is just a base for further implementation. The problem has already been solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following advices from David Schwartz and The Badger, I did rebuild the project and this did the trick. Probably, the file was not recompiled with a normal build.